# "Invalid Multi Send contract address" on Harmony

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I'm using `@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk` to connect to a safe on Harmony Mainnet. This exact same code is used on other EVM based chains without issues.

Stacktrace:

```
instrument.ts?6969:130 Error: Invalid Multi Send contract address
    at EthersAdapter.getMultiSendContract (EthersAdapter.ts?461a:103:13)
    at ContractManager.init (contractManager.ts?d7ef:56:48)
    at async Function.create (contractManager.ts?d7ef:20:5)
    at async Safe.init (Safe.ts?c8f6:110:29)
    at async Function.create (Safe.ts?c8f6:92:5)
```

Code:

```js
const safeAddress = '0x23725daFc71D6ea68Df50E5dE2faAB35751EF7bd';
const ethers = await import("ethers");
const { EthersAdapter, default: Safe } = await import(
  "@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk"
);
const signer = await requestSigner();
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signer });
const safe = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress });
```

This is the Gnosis Safe we're testing with: https://multisig.harmony.one/#/safes/0x23725daFc71D6ea68Df50E5dE2faAB35751EF7bd/transactions
We've also tested using `one1yde9mt78r4h2dr04pew7974tx463aaaaz2x5mf` as the safeAddress, but that throws errors about the address not being valid.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet is correct.

The message `Error: Invalid Multi Send contract address` is expected when using the SDK connected to Harmony Mainnet. Currently the Safe Core SDK v2.0.0 uses the package `safe-deployments` v1.8.0 to get the addresses of the Safe contracts deployed in different networks, which doesn't include Harmony network.

I'll create a new release of the Safe Core SDK with a newer version of the `safe-deployments` package that includes Harmony.

Meanwhile, you can get the deployed contract addresses in Harmony from here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets/v1.3.0 and add the property `contractNetworks` to the `Safe.create()` params with those values.

Check here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#create-1 the documentation regarding the property `contractNetworks` for more info:

```
import { ContractNetworksConfig } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'

const id = await ethAdapter.getChainId()
const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
  [id]: {
    multiSendAddress: '<MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS>',
    safeMasterCopyAddress: '<MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS>',
    safeProxyFactoryAddress: '<PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS>'
  }
}

const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress, contractNetworks })
```

Comment: How can we find the safe contract addresses? For KCC chain, I managed to find the safe proxy factory [here](https://explorer.kcc.io/en/address/0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2), I also found `GnosisSafe` and `GnosisSafeL2` contracts, but I can't find the other ones. If I have existing transactions made through a safe wallet with them, is it possible to extract from it? I'm keen on making a PR in your repo adding KCC and a few other networks, just not sure how to find these contracts. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like the contract addresses are deterministic, so for KCC at least the contracts seem to be the same as ETH and a few other chains. I was update to execute txs on KCC Safe. I'll check on other chains and raise PRs if all good. On another note, I wasn't sure what is `safeMasterCopyAddress` (I couldn't find this in the json assets), but I assumed this is the actual GnosisSafe or GnosisSafeL2 contract address (which one to use depends on the chain and the `isL1SafeMasterCopy` flag), correct me if I'm wrong.